# Getting Json returns true or false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a switch statement which return true or false and and an if and else statement I then use it to make some more validation.

Because the value is getting send on an input field using ajax. I want PHP to return true or false.

I have try this using JSON and I use an alert to test what I am getting back and its just a lot of html.

```
$a = isset($_POST['ccode']) ? $_POST['ccode'] : NULL;

    function isValid($Code) {
        switch ($Code){
            case "123":
            case "45545":
             return true;
        default: 
            return false;
        }
    }

if(isValid($a)) {
        $correct = "correct";
       echo json_decode($correct);
    }
    else {
        $incorrect = "incorrect";
        echo json_decode($incorrect);
    }
```

**AJAX**

```
 $('#ccode').blur(function() {
    var code = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
          url: 'index.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data:{
            ccode:code
          },
          success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          }
  });
```

*when you see alert(data)*
I am going to replace it with

```
if (data == false) {
//do this
}

});
```

My code doesn't return true or false from php and in the alert it just output a lot of html from my index page.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: why are echoing json_decode ? it should be json_encode

Comment: @abbiya thanks but my `if (data == true)` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is not `true` or `false` but `"correct"` or `"incorrect"`.

If you compare `data` with those values you'll likely get better results:

```
if (data === "correct") {
    // correct
} else {
    // incorrect
}
```

Oh yea, and you're using `json_decode` instead of `json_encode`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, _"does not work"_ is not a description I can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your PHP

```
echo json_decode($incorrect);
```

to

```
echo json_enecode(array("success"=>$incorrect));
```

And then in javascript parse this json.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your PHP

```
echo json_decode($incorrect);
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=>false, "message"=>$incorrect));
```

And then in javascript parse this json.

and do this way in jquery

```
if (data.error == false) {
//do this
}
```

Comment: what are those. post em

Answer (score 0):

Your $correct variable should be an array like this

```
$correct = ['isValid'=> true]
```

And then you encode that

In your success jquery callback function, you can debug it to check result value

```
alert(data.isValid)
```